# 90's style theme on Ask Different!

Tags: discussion

What's this theme on Ask Different? What's the reason behind enabling it?

[image]

Comment: See https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=April+fool&tab=newest :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It’s a party!

[Announcing the Stack Exchange Time Machine](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/326036/announcing-the-stack-exchange-time-machine)

(And kind of an education.) There are actually elements of this design that are useful / helpful which is why they were chosen back in the 90’s when everyone was experimenting about how to show the structure that the code uses for html.

But mostly a party and a reminder that shared experiences will make an annoyance to most be a reminiscence to others. Also, it’s a reminder that things change.

I’m totally planning to leave it enabled for as long as the hilarity lasts. Especially the guest book where everyone’s [id (or in the original das Es)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Id,_ego_and_super-ego) is running amok on the sugar high.

Comment: So far, I’m having more fun the longer I leave it enabled.

Comment: as far as I can tell the guestbook isn't real... unless there are like 4 or 5 people posting the same 4 or 5 posts over and over. My post showed up and scrolled away and never bounced back into the rotation.

Comment: That’s what makes it so fun. FFFFIIIIRRRSSSTTT! And such hilarity - a hell banned echo chamber was actually implemented and people are poking at it (me included). We love to explore and shiny things apparently.

Comment: Maybe it's the [Buzz Killington](https://familyguy.fandom.com/wiki/Buzz_Killington) in me but this feels like everything I disliked about the 90s Internet and the 90s in general.

Comment: @Allan I didn't realize there were unicorn farts from the cursor until just now. The iOS experience wasn't as full on the nose as what anyone with a mouse pointer was experiencing. Wow!

Comment: The unicorn farts were a close 2nd to this [abhorrent thing](https://www.picgifs.com/graphics/u/under-construction/graphics-under-construction-205618.gif) from back then.